# How to append a span tag and give each id a new name

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input, appendchild

I have 3 inputs that are nestled inside a span tag (I'm using span and not li because I have many li's in my code). I have a javascript function that appends each span tag (which includes the 3 inputs). I need each input to have a specific id name. Not sure how to do this, I'm learning javascript right now so forgive me for I'm a noob.

In my function I have the appendchild working for the span tag. At the bottom of the code I have a for loop that I wrote to append an ul/li and that name works. But I can't get that same functionality to work for the span tags.

How can I append child and each time I appendchild that the inputs get a new id name?

Here is my code so far:

```
            function budgetList(){

            var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0];
            var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
            var budgetListing = document.getElementById("budget-listing");
            var append = budgetListing.appendChild(cln);

            var expenseName = document.getElementById('expenseName');
            var expectedExpense = document.getElementById('expectedExpense');
            var actualExpense = document.getElementById('actualExpense');


            var ul = document.createElement("ul");
            document.body.appendChild(li);

            for(var i = 0; i <= 0; i++){
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.className = "budget-list" + i;

                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.innerHTML = "<input type='text'>";
                // a.innerHTML = "Subfile " + i;

                var att = document.createAttribute("class");
                att.value = "budgeting" + i;


                li.appendChild(a);
                ul.appendChild(li);

            }

        }
```

Here is the html

```
        <button onclick="budgetList()">Add New Row</button>
        <input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()" />
        <ul id="budget-listing">
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="expenseName">
                <input type="text" id="expectedExpense">
                <input type="text" id="actualExpense">
            </span>        
        </ul>
```

Comment: why do you need an id? do you have nomenclature prerequisites ?

Comment: *"I'm using span and not li because I have many li's in my code."* I'm not sure I understand the reasoning here. What matters is not how many instances of a tag exist in your document, but rather whether each tag is used properly. [Span tags don't go directly within Lists.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) I'm not sure what a list is if it's just a series of form inputs either. Perhaps a table would be more appropriate. What does `save` do?

Comment: You realize your for function only runs once right?

Comment: Also I'd recommend using a div tag not a span tag. And another thing if you use classes then it doesn't matter how many of an element you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

**1)** `<ul>` stands for Unordered List and `<ul>` elements expect their children to be `<li>` elements (which you can remember as List Item). So, while some browsers may be forgiving of you appending spans to your `<ul>` tag, it's not considered good practice. And is technically a [violation of the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

**2)** Your loop will only run exactly once. You'll see it's starting with variable `i` initialized at 0 and will only run as long as `i<=0` which will only ever be true on the first iteration because afterwards you increment (`i++`) which means the second time through `i` will equal 1 and 1 is NOT less than or equal to 0. So, in this case there's no need to use a loop at all.

**3)** Your code is a little disjointed from what you requested and what the page context is suggesting. It appears to me, when the user clicks the button you want to duplicate the span with 3 inputs. If this is indeed the case, then I offer the following solution...

```
function budgetList(){
        // You get the span that will serve as a template, good
        var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0];

        // you clone it, good
        var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);

        //next we want to modify the IDs of the child spans.
        // A good way to do this is to use a unique number that will change with every step
        // There a few ways to get a unique number each time
        // I propose taking the number of span groups
        var budgetListing = document.getElementById("budget-listing");
        var uniqueNumber = budgetListing.childNodes.length;

        // Now we update all the ids using the unique number
        cln.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].setAttribute('id', "expenseName_"+uniqueNumber);
        cln.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1].setAttribute('id', "expectedExpense_"+uniqueNumber);
        cln.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[2].setAttribute('id', "actualExpense_"+uniqueNumber);

        // and write our new span group into the container
        budgetListing.appendChild(cln);
}
```

Let me know if I made any incorrect assumptions or if this is close to what you're requesting. JavaScript and its interaction with HTML can be confusing at first, but stick with it!

**EDIT:** Didn't realize getElementById wasn't a function... Replaced with getElementsByTagName

Comment: This is awesome! I think this is what i am looking for. Yes I intentionally had the loop start from 0 and end on 0 because I just wanted to create 1 every time the button was clicked. This looks like what i need though, I'm trying to apply it, but I'm getting an error in the js console that says cln.getElementById('expenseName').setAttribute('id', "expenseName_" + i); is not a function. Do you know why it's saying that? I tried creating a function for it and it still didn't work. Also, I tried rearranging it a bit and still getting the same error. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I guess that function doesn't exist for normal nodes (my bad). I updated the code to now use elementsByTagName instead. Should give the same result.